# Can't use the Yocto-Watt module with Python under linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I m trying to measure a machine’s power consumption using Yocto-watt. everything goes well under Windows but it’s not working under Linux or raspberry pi (CM4) .
the problem is that he didn’t know the module yoctopuce while I can import it in a new python file.

I expect an output of my code that provide me the energy consumption mesured
this is the code :
https://github.com/OussMann/Yocto-watt-power-consumption.git

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Yoctopuce support directly, you'll get an answer. I know because I work there :-)